# Count number of times a record is refrenced in another table using LINQ-To-SQL

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL Server table named `DeficiencyTag` and its PK is an integer named `DeficiencyTagID`. It will have a couple hundred records. There's another table named `Deficiency` that references a particular `DeficiencyTagID`. There will be millions of these eventually.

What I need to do is make a list of the top 10 `DeficiencyTag` records based on the number of times each `DeficiencyTagID` is referenced from the `Deficiency` table.

The only way I can think of is having to manually loop through each `DeficiencyTag` record and count all Deficiency records that reference it. That sounds really slow and messy.

Is there a better way? I'm using LINQ-To-SQL for my DB interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your comment

```
var query = (from dt in dataContext.DeficiencyTags
             let count = dt.Deficiencies.Count
             orderby count descending
             select new { DeficiencyTag = dt, Count = count}).Take(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is a relationship in the designer between DeficiencyTag and Deficiency:

```
var query = dataContext.DeficiencyTags
  .OrderByDescending(dt => dt.Deficiencies.Count())
  .Take(10);
```

Comment: See I knew it was simple. Yes there is a relationship

Comment: What about finding the # of times each of those top 10 were referenced?